# Find all the stored Procedures that use a cursor in SQL Server using Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible  list out all the Stored Procedures that uses cursor in a  SQL Server using SQL Query. Please advise me.

Comment: You tagged Mysql and Oracle, but you're talking about SQL Server; please edit tag according to your DBMS.

Answer (score 9):

```
 select * from sys.sql_modules where definition like '%CURSOR FOR %'
```

if you are looking for currently open cursors ,you can use this query:

```
SELECT creation_time, cursor_id, name, c.session_id, login_name   
FROM sys.dm_exec_cursors(0) AS c   
JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions AS s ON c.session_id = s.session_id
```